# Out of the box browser Geolocation is slightly less accurate then production websites

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, location

I'm checking out my Geolocation on a laptop.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lon1 = position.coords.longitude;
   });
}
```

lat and lon are giving slightly different outputs then what the same browser is outputting on a site like http://whereamirightnow.com/

Are they using some Google libraries to improve the accuracy or something?

Comment: Did you try researching how `navigator.geolocation` works? It is well documented.... Let google be your friend

Comment: Well its confusing whether google maps or leafet will create different outputs or if it is browser dependent. I think it's a fair question.

Comment: Well if you don't understand how the data source is generated how can you make comparisons? On non GPS enabled devices all the request can use is IP

Comment: Trial,error and reasoning so far.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using this gave me the more precise longitude and latitude that other sites were producing by enabling high accuracy. Looks like Leaflet did it under the hood which confused me.

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```